# How do I implement UISearchbar on a UITableview?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uisearchbar

I am trying to add a UISearchBar to a UITableviewController that gets data from a db call. I added uisearchbar above the tableview in storyboard and made the outlet added delegate in class declaration and viewdidload.  Code seems right but I am getting no reaction when typing in the searchClients function.  Not sure what I am missing.  No errors showing in console.

```swift
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {

    var CompanyID = ""
    var CompanyName = ""
    var ClientList = [Client]()
    var filteredArray = [Client]()
    let URL_SERVICE = "https://fetch.php"

    @IBOutlet var searchClients: UISearchBar!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        searchClients.delegate = self

        filteredArray = ClientList

        // omitted call to get data, as it loads fine initially

    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return filteredArray.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Client", for: indexPath)
        let client = filteredArray[indexPath.row]
        let title = client.Name
        cell.textLabel?.text = title
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.CompanyID = filteredArray[indexPath.row].CompanyID
        self.CompanyName = filteredArray[indexPath.row].Name
    }


    func searchClients(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        //let text: String = self.searchClients.text ?? ""

        print("search for \(searchText)")

        self.filteredArray = []

        if (searchText == "") {
            self.filteredArray = self.ClientList
        } else {
            for item in self.ClientList {
                if (item.Name.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())) {
                    self.filteredArray.append(item)
                }
            }
        }
        print(filteredArray)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

What am I missing here that keeps searchBar function from firing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not implementing any method from the `UISearchBarDelegate` since your `searchClients` function is not correctly named. You will need to rename it to [`searchBar`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisearchbardelegate/1624299-searchbar) to actually implement the function from the delegate protocol.

```swift
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String)
```

##### Few Nitpicks

1. In Swift we are naming properties by starting with a lowercase letter

```swift
var companyID = ""
var companyName = ""
var clientList = [Client]()
var filteredArray = [Client]()
let urlService = "https://fetch.php"
```

2. You can skip every `self.` you are adding as a prefix when referencing to a property or function within the scope of the declaring type.

```swift
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    companyID = filteredArray[indexPath.row].companyID
    companyName = filteredArray[indexPath.row].name
}
```

3. Its much cleaner when protocol conformances are implemented using extensions so the code is nicely separated and they do not mix with each other.

```swift
extension TableViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        //let text: String = self.searchClients.text ?? ""

        print("search for \(searchText)")

        filteredArray = []

        if searchText == "" {
            filteredArray = clientList
        } else {
            filteredArray = clientList.filter { item in
                item.name.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
            }
        }
        print(filteredArray)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: omfg i knew it was something simple.  thanks a lot!